# Does deleting a content type also delete all nodes of that type?

Tags: 7

I know I can delete all nodes of a content type, keeping the content type, through bulk operations or such. If I'm not interested in keeping the content type, can I just delete the content type itself and all nodes will be gone with it?

This is the message I see when hitting the delete link for a content type, on Drupal 7.58.

> [image: screenshot]

Translated from French, that is:

> [Content type name] is used by 3 pieces of content on your site. It could be impossible to display them or to modify them correctly if you delete the content type.

The displayed message does not lead me to think outright that the nodes will be deleted, just that I might not be able view or edit them.

Comment: you need to delete first all those nodes, if you dont, you are not allowed to delete conten type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The confirmation message that Drupal 7.58 shows in English is the following one, where *%type* is the content type name and *@count* the number of nodes.

> %type is used by @count pieces of content on your site. If you remove %type, you will not be able to edit the %type content and it may not display correctly.

Drupal 7.58 shows that warning, but it lets you delete the content type. What that warning says it's correct: Once the content type used by existing nodes is deleted, those nodes cannot be anymore deleted; they also won't display correctly, since the function that deletes a content type ([`node_type_delete()`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/7.58/modules/node/node.module#L652)) deletes also the fields added to those nodes (with [`field_attach_delete_bundle()`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/7.58/modules/field/field.attach.inc#L1394)).

In Drupal 7.90, the latest Drupal 7 release available now, if you try to delete a content type for which there are nodes, Drupal won't allow you to delete it. It will tell you you need to first delete all the nodes of that content type.

For example, if I try to delete the *Basic Page* content type after I created a *Basic Page* node, instead of the confirmation form, Drupal will show me the following message (although the page title will be *Are you sure you want to delete the content type Basic page?*).

> Basic page is used by 1 piece of content on your site. You cannot remove this content type until you have removed all of the Basic page content.

> [image: screenshot]

Although Drupal 7.58 allows you to delete a content type for which there are nodes, it's preferable to first delete the existing nodes of the content type that is going to be deleted, following these steps.

- On admin/content, select the content type you want to delete in *type*
- Click on *Filter*
- The list at the bottom of the page will show only the nodes of that content type

  > [image: screenshot]
- Click on the checkbox shown on the right of *Title*, in the header
- Select *Delete selected content* from *Update options* (from the list that shows *Publish selected content*)
- Click on the *Update button*

  > [image: screenshot]

As side note, Drupal 7.58 isn't anymore secure. The following security issues has been fixed, in releases created after Drupal 7.58. (These are the last five fixed security issues.)

- [Drupal core - Moderately critical - Improper input validation - SA-CORE-2022-003](https://www.drupal.org/sa-core-2022-003), fixed in Drupal 7.88
- [Drupal core - Moderately critical - Cross Site Scripting - SA-CORE-2022-001](https://www.drupal.org/sa-core-2022-001) and [Drupal core - Moderately critical - Cross Site Scripting - SA-CORE-2022-002](https://www.drupal.org/sa-core-2022-002), fixed in Drupal 7.86
- [Drupal core - Critical - Third-party library - SA-CORE-2021-004](https://www.drupal.org/sa-core-2021-004), fixed in Drupal 7.82
- [Drupal core - Critical - Cross-site scripting - SA-CORE-2021-002](https://www.drupal.org/sa-core-2021-002), fixed in Drupal 7.80

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Very strange. The message I get when deleting a content type is (I am translating from French site translation): "<Content type name> is used by <N> contents on your site. It could be impossible to display them or to modify them correctly if you delete the content type". As you can see, the displayed message does not lead me to think outright that the nodes will be deleted, just that I might not be able view or edit them. After checking, Drupal does allow me to delete the content type without deleting the nodes first. I am on Drupal 7.58 at the moment.

Comment: The screenshots I shown are for Drupal 7.90. I will verify which difference there are between Drupal 7.58 and Drupal 7.90 and update my answer accordingly.